# Why does my chewie video player not work?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been using `Chewie` to play videos on a mobile app I've been making (new to this) and it has been working for the past 2 weeks. Recently, everything stopped working and I can't even get a video to play in the base starter app. The starter app (with the incrementCounter button) works fine, but when I change it to display a `Chewie` player,  it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _chewieController = ChewieController(
    videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.asset('sample.mp4'),
    autoInitialize: true,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Chewie(controller: _chewieController)),
    );
  }
}
```

You can see from the screenshot below that I have the local video in my flutter project, and also declared as a dependency in `pubspec.yaml`.

[image]

I've also tried network videos and they don't work too (although with other errors).

When I run it with an iPhone 13 iOS Simulator (the same one that has been working the past 2 weeks), it crashes before starting.

[image]

When I run it with Chrome or an Android Emulator (Pixel 2 API31, same one that has been working the past 2 weeks), I get this (the error log below is from the android simulator):

```
nathan@Nathans-MBP-3 whatisgoingon % flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics
artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             77.4s
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...                 7.3s
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...                     167ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

 Running with sound null safety 

An Observatory debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:50796/gkkCChfmcss=/
W/e.whatisgoingo(14362): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/ExoPlayerImpl(14362): Init 511a82 [ExoPlayerLib/2.14.1] [emulator64_x86_64_arm64, sdk_gphone64_x86_64, Google, 31]
I/Choreographer(14362): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available
at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:50796/gkkCChfmcss=/
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:580)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource$AssetDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/smaple.mp4
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource.open(AssetDataSource.java:87)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:201)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1016)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:417)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/smaple.mp4
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:881)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource.open(AssetDataSource.java:68)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14362):       ... 7 more
E/flutter (14362): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
```

Flutter doctor:

```
nathan@Nathans-MBP-3 whatisgoingon % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale
    en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Am I doing something wrong? I tried to copy code from different examples online (from the Chewie example github and other tutorials) and from my previous attempts that have worked, but to no avail...

edit: Tried a suggestion to downgrade Chewie to 1.2.1. This is the new error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:51753/N8pSDCE3K_U=/ws
W/e.whatisgoingo(15346): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/ExoPlayerImpl(15346): Init cc79bb8 [ExoPlayerLib/2.14.1] [emulator64_x86_64_arm64, sdk_gphone64_x86_64, Google, 31]
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:580)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource$AssetDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/sample.mp4
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource.open(AssetDataSource.java:87)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:201)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1016)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:417)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/sample.mp4
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:881)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.AssetDataSource.open(AssetDataSource.java:68)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):       ... 7 more
```

Comment: you checked this on real device? Please check this on real device as in Chewie documentation mentioned that it works on simulator only if you are on flutter 1.26.0 or above. So First check on real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dependencies:
  chewie: ^1.2.1
```

Add This There Latest Version 1.2.2 has some issue

Comment: I tried it again and got a different error. I updated my original question, you can see it there.

Comment: Can I ask how you found out about this issue? I'd like to learn to avoid similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This Exception is Because your File is not found :

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(15346):   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/sample.mp4
```

Check the Flutter_asset folder add the file correctly .
thanks

Comment: okay that was it. awarded the bounty to your first answer. thanks.